# How can I spy on communication between a process and a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, embedded-linux, tty, pty

I have a Linux process developed by a third-party that communicates with a terminal.  For debugging I want to see the communication going back in forth.

One might think `cat` would do the trick (to see one direction):

```
    ./third-party-app &
    cat /dev/tty
```

...but it does not.  Rather, `cat` will steal half of the data intended for the application, which is pretty much worthless.

third-party-app is hard-coded to assume `/dev/tty`.

One way I found to spy on the communication is to rename the `/dev/tty` device to, say, `/dev/real_tty` and create a named pipe called `/dev/tty` in its place.  Then running:

```
    cat /dev/real_tty | tee /dev/tty &
```

...will at least let me see the output of `/dev/real_tty`, by copying the data from `/dev/real_tty` to the named pipe `/dev/tty` and `stdout`.

This sort of works but it feels really dodgy, and relies on the trickery of replacing the device.  It also doesn't work in both directions, because named pipes only carry data in one direction.

What's the right way to do this?

If anyone's wondering, the TTY device is a RS-232 link to a microcontroller. The information is not sensitive or secured. All processes (application and spies) can run as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [slsnif](http://sourceforge.net/projects/slsnif/). It does exactly what you want, or if you're interested in writing one yourself the source is available to see how it works.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I'll take a look and see how it goes.

Comment: It does at least half the job without "stealing" data from the stream, although it doesn't show data being sent to the serieal port.  I may have not found the right options yet.

Comment: Annoyingly I've had to do this at least once before (it was to log a process going over ssh) but I can't find any notes on how I did it or remember the details. The slightly more convoluted way is to use psuedo ttys. Vague memory says that one pair is opened as /dev/tty (probably using symlinks as they have strange names /dev/pttym and /dev/pttyc) and the other end connects to the real tty device. It's more complex as you'll need to write a C wrapper that selects on the FDs and passes blocks back and forth while saving a copy to disk.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using [strace/ltrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace)? You can see the system calls it is making, in particular you can see the write/ioctl etc calls being made.

Answer (score 2):

[RS-232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232)? Just tap the RxD/TxD/GND lines with clips. It's been a forever since I've seen any device even care about DCD, DTR, etc.

Comment: That's cheating! :).  Absolutely, that would work, but getting the RS-232 output interleaved with the third party app's stdout debug messages be very helpful for solving timing problems.

Answer (score 1):

There are some alternatives:

Do It Youself with GDB: [Redirecting Output from a Running Process](http://etbe.coker.com.au/2008/02/27/redirecting-output-from-a-running-process/)

[CryoPID](http://cryopid.berlios.de/) allows you to capture the state of a running process in Linux and save it to a file. This file can then be used to resume the process later on, either after a reboot or even on another machine.

[Distributed MultiThreaded CheckPointing](http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/) is a tool to transparently
checkpointing the state of an arbitrary group of programs spread
across many machines and connected by sockets.

Comment: The question is not about std output. It is about the app writing to a specific device, in particular a link to a microcontroller.

Comment: Close, but I don't think that will do it.  I am interested in both the input and output.  The application might use a single file descriptor for both reading and writing the TTY, and I am then left with the same problem I had before with the named pipes.  The TTY is not stdin/stdout.

I was also hoping for something a little less invasive than breaking in with gdb....

Comment: @Moron so what? You don't *have* to pick 1 as the number of the fd you replace :)

Comment: @hobbs: If it is a device on which the app does some ioctl, then redirecting to a pipe might not work! I hope you get my point now.

Comment: @Moron: good point -- the app does use ioctl to configure the RS-232 baud rate

Answer (score 1):

The `script` program exists to do this using psudo-terminal.  The device `/dev/tty` is usually special and refers to the current process's controlling terminal, so you may not have had to resort to renaming things.

`script` opens a psudo-terminal and then runs another instance of your shell with that new shell as its controlling terminal (so `/dev/tty` refers to this psudo-terminal for this shell and its child processes).  The -c option lets you run a particular command rather than your shell.

The main problem with `script` is that it is impossible to tell which way the data captured in the output file (`./typescript` by default) was going -- data flowing both ways is dumped to the same file and looks similar to what appears on the screen when using an interactive terminal (except for including escapes, carriage returns, and goofy stuff like that as well as the normally displayed characters).

Anyway, I know that this question has long since been answered, but I thought that if anyone were to search for a similar solution and were not using a real serial port this may help them.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple (not for me at least), but a mechanism that should work for the tty serial drivers is a [line discipline](http://www.linux.it/~rubini/docs/serial/serial.html).

Answer (score 0):

People here have already made good suggestions, but here's another:

You can also write a shared library with your own `write()` that does some work before calling the `write()` from `libc.so`.  Then you can use the `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable to load your library when the process starts.

Comment: s/LDD_PRELOAD/LD_PRELOAD/  Unfortunately, SO won't allow making a one char edit even when it is a syntax error fix so I have to use a comment, sorry.

Comment: @arielf - You're right.  Edited.  Though looking back at this 5 years later I don't think it's a great answer.

Comment: :) I think it could have been a great answer if it was more complete. Include an actually working code snippet (e.g. how can `write` avoid calling itself when it calls the libc entry-point with the same name) and compilation line to create the preloaded module.  This is very valuable because it is a general solution to many similar problems: "how to slightly modify something in libc that already exists."

Answer (score 0):

Use socat:

```bash
# socat -v -v /dev/real_tty exec:"./third-party-app",pty,ctty,setsid,echo=0
```

The `-v` option should show communication between the TTYs.

Here's a nice example reference:

- [SOCAT Examples](https://gist.github.com/mario21ic/c09f0a648130ad6a91abdde41cb011c8)